# SC.Widget.Events.LOAD_PROGRESS isn't firing on the Widget Embed

Tags: javascript

the SC.Widget.Events.LOAD_PROGRESS doesn't seem to be firing on widget embed. I'm noticing a good amount of people bouncing from my site while they are waiting for the music to start playing. It would be great to provide them with visual feedback.

Comment: Same here. It seems LOAD_PROGRESS has never really worked.